# Question: How to use 'brew' to provide a C system library for a Swift Package target dependency?

Tags: swift-package-manager

How does one use `SystemPackageProvider.brew(…)` to provide a C/C++ system library for a Swift Package target dependency?

After some searching, it seemed that the following should work:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.4

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "JustOpenCV",
    dependencies: [ ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "JustOpenCV",
            dependencies: ["opencv"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "JustOpenCVTests",
            dependencies: ["JustOpenCV"]),
        .systemLibrary(name: "opencv",
            pkgConfig: "opencv",
            providers: [ .apt(["opencv-dev"]), .brew(["opencv"]) ])
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: CXXLanguageStandard.cxx14
)
```

Note: the library has already been installed via `brew install opencv`.

However, the following error occurs…

> *error: Source files for target opencv should be located under 'Sources/opencv', or a custom sources path can be set with the 'path' property in Package.swift*

Both the suggested error remedies imply not using the `SystemPackageProvider`. Is there a way to use `SystemPackageProvider` for a Homebrew installed library?

Repository: [JustOpenCV](https://github.com/marc-medley/JustOpenCV)

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking into adding Swift Package Manager support to a number of C and C++ libraries, so figured I'd take a shot at this. After hitting a number of dead ends, I was finally able to get this to build by creating a modulemap based on [this one I came across](https://github.com/Slyce-Inc/swift-opencv/blob/50773e162072cc49e4ed2d09468de561b0c26465/Sources/Clibopencv/module.modulemap)

You can see the relevant changes to the sample project in [this commit](https://github.com/JrGoodle/JustOpenCV/commit/bee2c386332ac2e1f40cbfa2a7cf6877c6952b7a)

### Package.swift

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.4

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "JustOpenCV",
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "JustOpenCV",
            dependencies: ["opencv"]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "JustOpenCVTests",
            dependencies: ["JustOpenCV"]
        ),
        .systemLibrary(
            name: "opencv",
            pkgConfig: "opencv4",
            providers: [
                .apt(["opencv-dev"]),
                .brew(["opencv"])
            ]
        )
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: CXXLanguageStandard.cxx14
)
```

One thing to notice is that the `pkg-config` file is actually named `opencv4`. The name can be confirmed with `pkg-config`:

```sh
> pkg-config --list-all
...
opencv4                             OpenCV - Open Source Computer Vision Library
...
```

```sh
> pkg-config --cflags opencv4
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/include/opencv4
```

### Sources/opencv/module.modulemap

```
module opencv [system] {
  umbrella header "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
  link "opencv_core"
  link "opencv_shape"
  link "opencv_dnn"
  link "opencv_ml"
  link "opencv_objdetect"
  link "opencv_stitching"
  link "opencv_superres"
  link "opencv_videostab"
  link "opencv_calib3d"
  link "opencv_features2d"
  link "opencv_highgui"
  link "opencv_videoio"
  link "opencv_imgcodecs"
  link "opencv_video"
  link "opencv_photo"
  link "opencv_imgproc"
  link "opencv_flann"
  export *
}
```

The important thing to note is that [all of the libraries must be linked](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/263171977ebcd47f4aaca1202cff5a96c5158a64/Documentation/Usage.md#packages-that-provide-multiple-libraries)

### Build and Run

```sh
> swift build
[1/1] Planning build

ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_gapi.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_stitching.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_alphamat.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_aruco.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_bgsegm.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_bioinspired.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_ccalib.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_dnn_superres.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_dpm.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_face.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_freetype.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_fuzzy.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_hfs.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_img_hash.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)

ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_line_descriptor.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_mcc.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)

ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_rapid.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_reg.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_rgbd.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_sfm.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_saliency.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_stereo.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_structured_light.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_optflow.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)

ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_tracking.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_surface_matching.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_datasets.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_text.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_videostab.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_plot.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_videoio.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_wechat_qrcode.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_viz.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_shape.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_ml.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_video.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)

ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_dnn.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)

ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_xphoto.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_photo.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/libopencv_core.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.10)
[2/2] Linking JustOpenCV

* Build Completed!
```

```sh
> swift run
[1/1] Planning build

* Build Completed!
```

This opens a window that says "Hello World :)" and when a key is pressed it closes.

### Caveat for usage in Swift

While this works for a C++ executable, I think it would require more work to be usable in Swift since [currently Swift can't directly call C++ code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CppInteroperabilityManifesto.md). I haven't tried it out, but I came across [this project](https://github.com/kobejean/opencv-swift) that seems to use [a fork of OpenCV](https://github.com/kobejean/opencv/blob/3e4c64d3549cc400496841d2af613d65933ddbcd/modules/core/misc/objc/swift-package-manager/Sources/OpenCVPackage.swift) to expose OpenCV as a module to Swift. I think an alternative solution would be to create a library target that links the C++ OpenCV system library and exposes the API's you need via Objective-C++